# What is the correct way to use sqlite cache and how could I check it?

Tags: c, sqlite, caching

After some study, I found that SQLite has two kinds of caches: "private page cache" and "shared cache". I try to use them and test the performance, but I really confuse about the usage of them. Following is my questions:

1. Will it open the cache by default?
2. What is correct way to open private page cache and shared cache?
3. Could I check the sqlite cache status by SQLITE_DBSTATUS_CACHE_USED and SQLITE_STATUS_PAGECACHE_USED? What is different between the two items?

My way to disable / enable private cache / enable shared cache are as following, are these right?

- **disable (open by default?):**

  ret = sqlite3_open_v2(db_name, db_handle,SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY , NULL);
- **enable private cache:**

  ret = sqlite3_open_v2(db_name, db_handle,
              SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY | SQLITE_OPEN_PRIVATECACHE, NULL);
- **enable shared cache:**

  ret = sqlite3_open_v2(db_name, db_handle,
          SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY | SQLITE_OPEN_SHAREDCACHE, NULL);

And I check the sqlite by looking at **SQLITE_STATUS_PAGECACHE_USED** and **SQLITE_DBSTATUS_CACHE_USED** now.

This is really stuck me. There is always a value for SQLITE_DBSTATUS_CACHE_USED even if I didn't enable the cache. For SQLITE_STATUS_PAGECACHE_USED, no matter I enable or disable the cache, there will not be 0 only when I add following code before I init the sqlite:

```
sqlite3_config(SQLITE_CONFIG_PAGECACHE, buf, sz, N);
```

It looks like the sqlite_open_v2 flag is not working without any reason??

Answer (score 1):

SQLite has a single kind of cache, the page cache, and it is always enabled.

When in shared-cache mode, multiple connections in the same process can share the page cache. So you will not see any difference as long as you are using a single connection.

(Shared-cache mode is intended for multithreaded servers running in a device with restricted memory; it's probably not useful for you.)